# How can I apply the onSaved method on my dropdownlist

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new on flutter, and would like to know how can I apply the onSaved method on my drpdownList.
Please Help!

```
              Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*.3,
                              child: Text('Départ:', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*.5,

                                child: _fieldDropDown(_citiesdept, 0, 'depart'),
                                // onSaved: (value) => _citiesdept = value,


                            )
                          ],
                        ),
```

Comment: onSaved ? _fieldDropDown  ? your question is unclear. provide more code and context

Comment: Hi @Durdu, I'm now try to add more code but it's difficult to edit on StackOverflow can I add you to my Git in order to let you see my full code ?

Comment: Sure thing, let us have it :)

Comment: The problem is, I'd like to fetch the informations of my dropdownList after tap on validation button, now it's ok for the TextFormField, but don't know how to do the it for the dropdownList

Comment: can I please have your user name on git @Durdu

Comment: durduman is my user

Comment: Just add you @Durdu

Comment: are you sure ? :))

Comment: Hello @Durdu, I tried to apply the callback as you shown but got errors about number of arguments in '_fielDropDown child', so as I told you I'd like to fetch the informations in theses variables (String depart; String destination; String poids; String dimensions; String description)

Answer (score 0):

Will this solve your question?

if you want a callback to your widget you need to:

change

```
_fieldDropDown(List theList, int resultPosition, var dbField) {
// to 
_fieldDropDown(List theList, int resultPosition, var dbField, void Function(dynamic newValue) callback) {
```

make the call when required in the dropDown...

```
setState(() {

                  this.resultsList[resultPosition] = newValue;

// HERE is the callback:     
                  callback(newValue);

                  state.didChange(newValue);

                  print(

                      'The List result = ' + this.resultsList[resultPosition]);

                  //write newValue to a database field, which can be used in the override init to set the field originally

                });
```

and use it as you wish, for example ...

```
Container(
     width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*.5,
     child: _fieldDropDown(_citiesdept, 0, 'depart'),
     callback: (value) => print(value),
```

Comment: Hello @Durdu, I tried to apply the callback as you shown but got errors about number of arguments in  '_fielDropDown  child', so as I told you I'd like to fetch the informations in theses variables (String depart;
  String destination;
  String poids;
  String dimensions;
  String description;)

Comment: Hello @Durdu, I solved the problem by using another way, thank you for your help!